# Is a NS2 code workable in NS3?

Tags: ns2, ns-3

I have built up a code in NS2.35 and now want to take it to NS3 since I want to include open flow related bits in it ..is it possible to do so or is openflow easy to implement even in NS2 ?

Answer (score 1):

NS2 and NS3 are basically two different things, so there is no "straightforward" way to do transfer from one to the other.

I got stuck into similar situation in my recent project. Some helpful modules were built in NS2 and we want to use them. However, the limitation of NS2 makes us struggled during the past few weeks. After countless meetings and discussion, we finally decided to begin the transfer from NS2 to NS3. I would recommend you do the same thing if you are not too eager to get the simulation result from NS2.

BTW, the NS3 google group is quite help:)

Cheers,

Zeyu